# Multiprocess controller in python on RPi

Tags: python, daemon, multiprocess

Currently, my home brewery RPi controller logs and plots temperatures and a flowrate and operates as a thermostat. But the application is slow between monitoring updates. One idea is to split the temperature/flowrate/thermostat portion of the program as a separate process and have the GUI plot and interface routinely poll that process for temps and flow and to provide any changes to the set temperature of the thermostat.

I tried multithreading, but since the thermostat thread runs on a "while True" loop, it never finishes and the main program stops doing anything. Most discussions of multiprocessing talk of different chunks of data processing and then returning some results. Is multiprocessing the way to go? Is there some other way to handle this problem, like a thermostat daemon and a GUI that interacts with it?

Comment: _I tried multithreading, but since the thermostat thread runs on a "while True" loop, it never finishes and the main program stops doing anything._ Can you expand on this? Could you share at least part of your program? It's probably best to check if there is any way of improving the performance of the current program, before considering something like multiprocessing.

Comment: Here's my original post on a raspberrypi.org forum:

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=262066

Comment: Here's some sample output from the data logging file where I turned the flow on and off to see how long it took the raspberry to shut off the GPIO power.

Comment: Time20200117, RIMS, Mash, Flow, SetTemp, ElapsedTime
13:02:28,76.3,72.9,195,50,00:00:00:06
13:02:32,76.5,73.0,189,50,00:00:00:10
13:02:36,76.5,73.0,192,50,00:00:00:14
13:02:44,76.6,73.1,189,80,00:00:00:22
13:02:48,76.6,73.1,192,80,00:00:00:27
13:02:53,76.6,73.1,3,80,00:00:00:31
13:02:57,76.6,73.1,189,80,00:00:00:36
13:03:02,76.6,73.1,9,80,00:00:00:40
13:03:07,76.6,73.1,192,80,00:00:00:45
13:03:12,76.6,73.1,189,80,00:00:00:50
13:03:17,76.5,73.1,0,80,00:00:00:55
13:03:22,76.6,73.1,192,80,00:00:01:00
13:03:27,76.6,73.1,192,80,00:00:01:05

Comment: Alright, I’ll go read the other post!

Comment: Thank you for your help! Since my initial post, I've added the thermostat portion of the code. I also ran a test of the whole brewing system and discovered the time delay problem was more serious. As the program is running, the time delay increases. After about two hours, the program takes over 30 seconds to refresh. Admittedly, there are more points to plot, but the delay means my thermostat function  is unable to adjust for the longer and longer time it takes between refreshes. (I send pulses of GPIO high to the heater element.)

Comment: I researched memory leaks and issues with matplotlib, but nothing seems to work. Monitoring with the linux command, top, shows, after an hour, %mem increases from about 6% to 15% and %CPU rises from about 30% to 100%. I'm at a loss understanding what is going on.

Comment: My previous system used an Arduino to monitor the sensors and control and communicated, via serial, with an old netbook running a python program to do the plotting and logging. I did not have this delay problem. (I had problems with the serial communication and thought a solution was to move everything to a RPi, learning how to use the GPIO pins and creating a custom hat/shield.)

Comment: BTW, I try to post my code, but the Comment Box keeps saying I've got way too many characters, regardless of any Control-K or spaces beginning/end or curly braces.

Comment: I can confirm the issue is with the plot. When all code dealing with the plot is removed, the application runs as expected. The appending of data to the array variables that are plotted is also not an issue. Now trying to determine if problem is in PySimpleGUI, tkinter, or matplotlib.

Comment: _BTW, I try to post my code, but the Comment Box keeps saying I've got way too many characters, regardless of any Control-K or spaces beginning/end or curly braces._ That's fine, it's always best to share code in the main post anyway.